# A jquery multiple date selector with weekend selector?

Tags: jquery, plugins, calendar, datepicker

I need to create a calendar/datepicker like there is one on this page...
    http://www.villagevoice.com/calendar/?ref=navigation

i have used the datepicker ui of jquery to bring the datepicker and take a single value from it. But i cant seem to bring the functionalities there is already on the site.. is there any kind of plugin for that?

Comment: ok! what i did was to attach a datepicker to a div that contains a hidden input field for single date. thats how i was storing the value..but from jquery website i learned that the ui datepicker cant handle 2 instances of date. so for the time being to select a date range i just used two input fields..one for "from" and another for "to" and pop up the datepicker on focus...but thats not how it should be done..

Comment: Or you could use a DatePicker that is designed for a range of dates.

Comment: such as? I wanna select a range of dates just by clicking on the start and end date.

Comment: The answer I gave. The demo is here http://multidatespickr.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://dubrox.blogspot.com/2010/09/multiple-dates-picker-for-jquery-ui.html

Great extension to the jQuery DatePicker to select multiple dates.

Comment: But there is not something that i specifically want... I want to show the datepicker. Then I ll select a start date and then i ll select an end date and on doing that it will highlight the dates in between but the data sent to the server will only be two comma separated values..the start date and the end date...

Comment: @praveen the Calendar also has that functionality, you can set the maximum number of picks then select the range inside it.

Comment: it would be really nice if you can show me a working demo of my specific requirement..may be a fiddle.. thanks in advance.:)